# how to merge pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a df as df1

```
                       Userid         Price  
Time                                                        
2022-04-02 14:24:21  91127426  46697.000000 
2022-04-02 13:36:46  38041849  46901.500000  
2022-04-02 13:18:03  23796917  46770.000000
```

and other df as df2

```
            price_diff_bps  pnl_of_fills  
Userid                                  
38041849            -0.0       -1333.0  
91127426            -0.0       -5687.5
```

im trying to merge these two dataframes upon user id.

```
final_df=df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='Userid')
            

       Userid         Price  price_diff_bps  pnl_of_fills  
Time                                                        
2022-04-02 14:24:21  91127426  46697.000000  -0.0  -1333.0   
2022-04-02 13:36:46  38041849  46901.500000  -0.0  -5687.5
```

im missing the user id in final df, i need all the userid from the df1.

Comment: Seems need `final_df=df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='Userid', how='right')`

Comment: yes, this only..

Comment: It is correct closed dupe, so removed answer.

Comment: but your answer is not mentioned there in the dupe.. how to understand these..

Comment: My first answer was wrong :) So if edit by `final_df=df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='Userid', how='right')` then dupe.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time anyway.. you are helping me alot.. thank you so much.. @jezrael in many problems..